# StartCoroutine is being called so many times (C# Unity)

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I'm creating a Pop up menu Option in Unity. Now my Problem here is that the coroutine i made in void update is being called so many times. What i mean by that is on my Unity Console the Debug.Logs are incrementing . It should not right because its already coroutine. Could some help me understand more coroutine and help me solve my little problem .

Here is my code:

```
[SerializeField]
GameObject Option;
[SerializeField]
Button btn,btn2;
[SerializeField]
GameObject open, close;

[SerializeField]
GameObject[] opt;
bool startFinding = false;
void Start()
{
    Option.SetActive(false);
    Button popUp = btn.GetComponent<Button>();
    Button popUp2 = btn2.GetComponent<Button>();
    popUp.onClick.AddListener(PopUpOption);
    popUp2.onClick.AddListener(ClosePopUp);


}

void Update()
{
    if (startFinding)
    {
        StartCoroutine(GameOptions());
    } 
}

IEnumerator GameOptions()
{

    //Get All the tags
    opt = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("MobileOptions");

    if (opt[0].GetComponent<Toggle>().isOn == true && opt[1].GetComponent<Toggle>().isOn == true)
    {
        Debug.Log("Disable first the check box then choose only 1 option between" + "'rendering'"+ "and" + "'livestreaming'");
    }
    //Livestreaming
    if (opt[0].GetComponent<Toggle>().isOn == true)
    {
        Debug.Log("Livestreaming Activate");
    } else 
    {
        Debug.Log("Livestreaming Deactivate");
    }
    //Rendering
    if (opt[1].GetComponent<Toggle>().isOn == true)
    {
        Debug.Log("Rendering Activate");
    } else
    {
        Debug.Log("Rendering Deactivate");
    }
    //Fog

    if (opt[2].GetComponent<Toggle>().isOn == true)
    {
        Debug.Log("Fog Activated");
    } else
    {
        Debug.Log("Fog Deactivated");
    }

    //Camera Effect
    if (opt[3].GetComponent<Toggle>().isOn == true)
    {
        Debug.Log("Camera Effect Activated");
    } else {
        Debug.Log("Camera Effect Deactivated");
    }
        yield return null;
}

void PopUpOption()
{
    startFinding = true;
    //Disable The Mobile Option Button
    open.SetActive(false);
    //Enable the Close Option Button
    close.SetActive(true);
    //activate the Mobile Options
    Option.SetActive(true);

}

void ClosePopUp()
{
    startFinding = false;
    //eanble the mobile option button
    open.SetActive(true);
    //disable the close option button
    close.SetActive(false);
    //deactivate the Mobile Option
    Option.SetActive(false);
}
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, the code's doing exactly what you asked it to. The `Update()` method is, of course, called repeatedly. And in that method, you start the co-routine as long as the `startFinding` field is set to `true`. So once the popup is displayed, I would absolutely expect your co-routine to be started many times (the `Update()` method is called dozens of times a second, normally). If you don't want it to keep being started, then...don't keep starting it!

Comment: All that said, it's not clear why you made that a co-routine in the first place...it has a straight-through execution path, without any sort of looping that would normally be found in a co-routine.

Comment: oh so you are saying sir it is normal because it is on my update function??

Comment: @PeterDuniho what do you mean by it has a straight-through execution path, without any sort of looping that would normally be found in a co-routine . i don't quite understand sir.

Comment: _"it is normal because it is on my update function?"_ -- yes, "normal" in the sense that that's exactly what you've written the code to do. I don't know what you _meant_ to do, so I can't say whether that's correct or not (and your question suggests it's not), but without knowing why you choose to write the co-routine in the first place and how you expected it to work, it's not possible to suggest an actual answer that would solve your problem.

Comment: _"what do you mean by it has a straight-through execution path, without any sort of looping that would normally be found in a co-routine"_ -- there are no looping statements, e.g. `while`, `for`, `foreach`, etc. In Unityd3, a co-routine executes from when it's called up to the first `yield return`, at which point control is returned to the caller. Then control resumes later, under control of the caller (which calls `MoveNext()` on the enumerator, but that's not important here), immediately following the `yield return`. Your method yields just once and then is done. Atypical for co-routines.

Comment: In other words, the co-routine you have doesn't behave the way co-routines usually do. A normal co-routine alternates between execution and yielding, with execution occurring periodically under the Unity3d runtime's control. Your co-routine executes and then is done. There does not appear to be any reason for it, since it never does any additional work after yielding. I believe what you really need is to go read and/or watch a tutorial discussing Unity3d co-routines. The Unity3d web site will have links to such.

Comment: Thank you sir . I'll change it later after i solve my problem . Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is how coroutines work:**

Let's say I have a couroutine function called MyRoutine (in your case, you called it GameOptions)

```
private IEnumerator MyRoutine()
```

Then, anywhere in my code, calling

```
StartCoroutine(MyRoutine));
```

Is going to simply call `MyRoutine` like any usual method. So if you call it in update, it will be called all the time, as any method would. This is not what you want. What make coroutines special is that you can use the **`yield`** keyword in them. There are many ways to use it but the most used (and simple) one is to do **`yield return null`**

**`yield return null` means "Stop this coroutine, but resume the execution on next frame".** You don't need to call any other function (certainly not StartCoroutine). The execution will resume next frame.

To go back to what you posted in your question, you wrote `yield return null` at the end. So your method is executing, and just at the end, stops and resumes next frame, but since there is nothing left to do, it exits on the next frame.

A typical way to use coroutines is to have the `yield return null` in a while loop, so when it resumes, it continues the loop. Here is an example that do it

```
private IEnumerator MyRoutine()
{
    while(running) //running is a member bool that you could set to false to exit
    {
        // Do all the stuff you want to do in ONE frame
        // ...
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

Typically, the StartCoroutine would be called in the Start() function, or later when an event is triggered.

If you want to know more about coroutine, or check that you understood them properly, check out this page: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html

or this video https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/coroutines

**// Edit: quickly present one useful option**

In the snippet above, the while loop is very similar to the Update function (the inside of the loop is executed each frame). One nice option is to replace

```
yield return null
```

by

```
yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime)
```

where `waitTime` is a the time you want to wait before resuming, in seconds

**// End of edit**

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `StartCoroutine()` in the `Update` method. Call it in another method and use a `while loop` inside your `coroutine` function if needed. Just control your `StartCoroutine()` outside of `Update` method

Comment: That's not really going to help the OP. It will stop it from being started repeatedly, but since the method isn't really a useful co-routine, there's no evidence that calling it just once outside of the `Update()` method is actually going to achieve what the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

Update is called every frame, if your condition is ever true, you launch your coroutine every frame.
Just set down your flag to only join 1 time.

```
void Update()
{
    if (startFinding)
    {
        startFinding = false;
        StartCoroutine(GameOptions());
    } 
}
```