# Playerprefs seems to not work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Now my mind is a bit messed up because of playerprefs i'm a noob to c#.
By the way . What i am doing is saving my settings in the menu that i created using toggles.
Here's my code :

```
[SerializeField]
GameObject Option;
[SerializeField]
Button btn,btn2;
[SerializeField]
GameObject open, close;

[SerializeField]
GameObject[] opt;
bool startFinding = false;

//settings
bool livestream;
bool rendering;
bool fog;
bool cameraeffect;

int live;
void Start()
{

    Option.SetActive(false);
    Button popUp = btn.GetComponent<Button>();
    Button popUp2 = btn2.GetComponent<Button>();
    popUp.onClick.AddListener(PopUpOption);
    popUp2.onClick.AddListener(ClosePopUp);

}

void Update()
{
    if (startFinding)
    {
        StartCoroutine(GameOptions());
    }
}

IEnumerator GameOptions()
{

    if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("SaveSettings"))
    {
        ActivateSettings();
        Debug.Log("Theres a data");
    } else
    {
        Debug.Log("Oops sorry there was no data");
    }

    //Get All the tags
    opt = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("MobileOptions");
    //fog , camera , livestream, rendering

    if (opt[0].GetComponent<Toggle>().isOn == true && opt[1].GetComponent<Toggle>().isOn == true)
    {
        Debug.Log("Disable first the check box then choose only 1 option between" + "'rendering'"+ "and" + "'livestreaming'");
    }
    //Livestreaming
    if (opt[0].GetComponent<Toggle>().isOn == true)
    {
        Debug.Log("Livestreaming Activate");
        livestream = true;
    } else 
    {
        Debug.Log("Livestreaming Deactivate");
        livestream = false;
    }
    //Rendering
    if (opt[1].GetComponent<Toggle>().isOn == true)
    {
        rendering = true;
        Debug.Log("Rendering Activate");
    } else
    {
        Debug.Log("Rendering Deactivate");
        rendering = false;
    }
    //Fog

    if (opt[2].GetComponent<Toggle>().isOn == true)
    {
        fog = true;
        Debug.Log("Fog Activated");
    } else
    {
        Debug.Log("Fog Deactivated");
        fog = false;
    }

    //Camera Effect
    if (opt[3].GetComponent<Toggle>().isOn == true)
    {
        cameraeffect = true;
        Debug.Log("Camera Effect Activated");
    } else {
        Debug.Log("Camera Effect Deactivated");
        cameraeffect = false;
    }

    SaveSettings();

    yield return null;
}

void SaveSettings()
{
    try { 
        //convert the bool to int
        live = livestream ? 1 : 0;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("SaveSettings", live);
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.LogError("Exception :" + ex);
    }
}
 void ActivateSettings()
{
    live = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("SaveSettings");
}
```

My playerprefs is i guess not working but my debug.log saying that it has a data. It is messsed up or I'm just missing something about playerprefs . Could someone point out what i am doing wrong. I don't want to be stucked here.

Comment: You're loading the data from PlayerPrefs into an integer that is immediately overwritten by `livestream ? 1 : 0`. `live` appears in no other context.

Comment: @Draco18s ow is that so sir. I'm just following the tuts and him is working . sorry for my bad english.

Comment: and also i tried changing `live = livestream ? 1 : 0; PlayerPrefs.SetInt("SaveSettings", live);` to `PlayerPrefs.SetInt("SaveSettings", livestream ? 1:0);` and `live = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("SaveSettings");` to `livestream = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("SaveSettings") == 1 ? true : false;`

Comment: When are you setting startFinding to true? Instead of setting startFinding to true, just call the GameOption method. Also, I don't see why it's a Coroutine?

Comment: `live` still does **nothing**. You want to read data from the save file then *put that data where it does some good.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i did was this and i know this coroutine is not really that big problem .

```
[SerializeField]
Button openButton, closeButton;
[SerializeField]
GameObject OPTION_UI;//parent
[SerializeField]
GameObject open_option_button, close_option_button;

[SerializeField]
GameObject[] settings;

[SerializeField]
Toggle[] toggle;

bool Found = false;
 void Start()
{
    OPTION_UI.SetActive(false);
    Button OPENBUTTON = openButton.GetComponent<Button>();
    Button CLOSEBUTTON = closeButton.GetComponent<Button>();
    OPENBUTTON.onClick.AddListener(OpenUI);
    CLOSEBUTTON.onClick.AddListener(CloseUI);

    toggle[2].isOn = true;
    //fog
    if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("SaveFog") == 1)
    {
        toggle[0].isOn = true;
    }
    else
    {
        toggle[0].isOn = false;
    }
    //camera
    if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("SaveCamera") == 1)
    {
        toggle[1].isOn = true;
    }
    else
    {
        toggle[1].isOn = false;
    }
    //livestreaming
    if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("SaveLiveStream") == 1)
    {
        toggle[2].isOn = true;
    }
    else
    {
        toggle[2].isOn = false;
    }
    //rendering
    if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("SaveRendering") == 1)
    {
        toggle[3].isOn = true;
    }
    else
    {
        toggle[3].isOn = false;
    }
} 


 void Update()
{
    if (Found)
    {
        StartCoroutine(GameOptions());
    } else
    { 
        StopCoroutine(GameOptions());
    }
}

IEnumerator GameOptions()
{

    /*
     * fog , camera
     * livestream, rendering
     * */

    //get the options
    settings = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("MobileOption");

    //fog
    if (toggle[0].isOn == true)
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("SaveFog", 1);
    } else
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("SaveFog", 0);
    }

    //camera
    if (toggle[1].isOn == true)
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("SaveCamera", 1);
    } else
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("SaveCamera", 0);
    }
    //livestream
    if (toggle[2].isOn == true)
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("SaveLiveStream" , 1);
    } else
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("SaveLiveStream", 0);
    }
    //rendering
    if (toggle[3].isOn == true)
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("SaveRendering", 1);
    } else
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("SaveRendering", 0);
    }

    yield return null;
}


//activate UI
void OpenUI()
{

    Found = true;
    open_option_button.SetActive(false);
    close_option_button.SetActive(true);
    OPTION_UI.SetActive(true);

}
//deactivate UI
void CloseUI()
{
    Found = false;
    open_option_button.SetActive(true);
    close_option_button.SetActive(false);
    OPTION_UI.SetActive(false);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48199790/startcoroutine-is-being-called-so-many-times-c-unity) before, You're calling `StartCoroutine(GameOptions())` in `Update` method that is wrong! That's because you're calling `SaveSettings()` over and over again and because of that `PlayerPrefs.SetInt("SaveSettings", live)` is calling too many times in `Update` method

Comment: so what should i do sir??

Comment: @NoobProgrammer at first, try to solve your previous issue to not call StartCoroutine in Update method, then try to add playerprefs